# Subquery with joins alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, alias

I'm trying to select some data however I'm having issues since this is a subquery and the data in the subquery is using aliases for the joins.  I would like it setup this was since I will be running aggregates on the subquery in different ways.  Here is an example.  I hope you understand what I'm trying to do here.  This is NOT The actual data I'm working with, therefore I would like to use the below approach.  The issue is I'm trying to query a sub-query which has an alias and which has a join that also has an alias.

Bear in mind, the below works if I just select main_query.FullState if I have 1 join, but since I am joining twice, I need to add an alias.  This is where I am having trouble.

```
USERTABLE
----------------

    Name    BirthState     LivingState
    David   CA             CA
    Roger   NY             PA
```

```
STATESTABLE
----------------
    State   FullState

    CA      California
    NY      New York
    PA      Philadelphia
```

```
select main_query.LivingTable.FullState, count(*) from (
    select * from USERTABLE
    join STATESTABLE LivingTable on USERTABLE.LivingState = STATESTABLE.State
    join STATESTABLE BirthTable on USERTABLE.BirthState = STATESTABLE.State
)main_query
```

Comment: You problem is that you are using `select *`. Never use `select *`. Always only select the columns you need, and alias as required.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You are completely right.  I ended up selecting the columns as much as a pain as it was (40+) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the alias of the joined table. You can't even access the "inner" table-alias, because it is out of the scope.

If you want retrieve two columns that have the same columnname in the original table, use a column-alias with AS.

Another thing: please use WITH for these cases. This greatly enhances readability.

```
WITH main_query AS
(
    select lt.FullState AS LivingFullState, bt.FullState AS BirthFullState
    from USERTABLE ut 
    join STATESTABLE lt on lt.LivingState = ut.State
    join STATESTABLE bt on bt.BirthState = ut.State
)
select LivingFullState, count(*) from main_query
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run "aggregate" and other type of queries without resorting to a "sub-query". simply use something like

```
Select living.FullState as "Living State", count(1)
  from USERTABLE user JOIN STATESTABLE living on living.LivingState = user.State
```

Something like the item below might also be useful

```
Select State, Sum(LivingStatePopulation) as "Living State Population", Sum(BirthStatePopulation) as "Birth State Population"
  from (Select living.FullState as "State", count(1) as "LivingStatePopulation", 0 as "BirthStatePopulation"
          from USERTABLE user JOIN STATESTABLE living on living.LivingState = user.State 
        UNION
        Select birth.FullState as "State", 0 as "LivingStatePopulation", count(1) as "BirstStatePopulation"
)
order by State
```